# Java manifest file

Tags: java, manifest

As a note, I am no Java Developer but I have limited knowledge from High School.
I was asked to make a simple program just to generate a report and then view it, et cetera (which worked).

I am ecstatic that it works but unfortunately I cannot get the `.jar` file to run once I have made it executable I am presuming that it is due to the manifest file not calling exactly what is needed.

I have looked online for help but cannot seem to grasp the concept.

Main class:

```
package writeBatchFile;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class mainFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("youwillneverfigurethisout");
        myFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton oneDayReport = new JButton("Create Day Report");
        JButton weekReport = new JButton("Create Week Report");
        JButton monthReport = new JButton("Create Month Report"); 
        JButton runBatch = new JButton("Run Batch File");
        JButton viewReport = new JButton("Open Report");
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        oneDayReport.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Please Click On Create Batch ");
        JLabel blank = new JLabel("File and then Run Batch File");

        myFrame.add(label);
        myFrame.add(blank);
        myFrame.add(oneDayReport);
        myFrame.add(weekReport);
        myFrame.add(monthReport);
        myFrame.add(runBatch);
        myFrame.add(viewReport);
        myFrame.add(exit);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setTitle("Report Generator");
        myFrame.setSize(400, 200);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        oneDayReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent write) {
                try {   
                    String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Input the Date for the report (ie: 04/07/2014-04/07/2014)");
                    String input2 = input1;
                    String line1 = "@echo";
                    String line2 = "C:\\sarg\\sbin\\sarg –d " + input1 + "-" + input2;
                    String line3 = "pause";

                    File file = new File("generateReport.bat");

                    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(line1);
                    bw.write("\r\n \r\n" + line2);
                    bw.write("\r\n \r\n" + line3);
                    bw.close();

                    System.out.println("Done");

                } catch(IOException c) {
                    c.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        weekReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent write) {
                try {   
                    String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please a 'from' date for the report (ie: 04/07/2014)");
                    String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a 'to' date for the report (ie: 11/07/2014");
                    String line1 = "@echo";
                    String line2 = "C:\\sarg\\sbin\\sarg –d -w " + input1 + "-" + input2;
                    String line3 = "pause";

                    File file = new File("generateReport.bat");

                    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                    if ( !file.exists())
                        file.createNewFile();

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(line1);
                    bw.write("\r\n \r\n" + line2);
                    bw.write("\r\n \r\n" + line3);
                    bw.close();

                    System.out.println("Done");

                } catch (IOException c) {
                    c.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        monthReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent write) {
                try {   
                    String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please a 'from' date for the report (ie: 04/07/2014)");
                    String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a 'to' date for the report (ie: 24/07/2014");
                    String line1 = "@echo";
                    String line2 = "C:\\sarg\\sbin\\sarg –d -w -m" + input1 + "-" + input2;
                    String line3 = "pause";

                    File file = new File("generateReport.bat");

                    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                    if ( !file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(line1);
                    bw.write("\r\n \r\n" + line2);
                    bw.write("\r\n \r\n" + line3);
                    bw.close();

                    System.out.println("Done");

                } catch(IOException c) {
                    c.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        runBatch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent read) {
                try {    
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start generateReport.bat");
                    p.waitFor();

                } catch(IOException ex) {
                    // Validate the case the file can't be accessed (not enough permissions)
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    // Validate the case the process is being stopped by some external situation     
                }
            }
        });

        viewReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent read) {

                try {    

                 // using this in real life, you'd probably want to check that the desktop
                 // methods are supported using isDesktopSupported()...

                 String htmlFilePath = "test.html"; // path to your new file
                 File htmlFile = new File(htmlFilePath);

                 // open the default web browser for the HTML page
                 Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());

                 // if a web browser is the default HTML handler, this might work too
                 Desktop.getDesktop().open(htmlFile);

                } catch(IOException ex) {
                    // Validate the case the file can't be accesed (not enought permissions)
                }
            }
        });

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent close) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my **manifest.mf** looks like such:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: mainFile.class
Main-Class: writeBatchFile.mainFile
```

As far as I am aware, It is due to the files I am importing such as `java.awt` and `java.io` but if *anyone* can write me a manifest file for this or tell me how to create it using either Eclipse or JCreator, I would *greatly* appreciate it.

Comment: there are several reasons why the jar file doesn't run. for instance, on the machine you try to run it on, does it have Java in the Environment Variables of your OS? if not, the OS won't know how to handle the jar, and thus not run it.

Comment: I have JRE installed, java updated to latest version... I have even created a test environment using a VM from EXSi on my server, so I have come to the conclusion that my manifest file is the issue

Comment: That `Class-Path` entry definitely doesn't look good to me. Can you show us the output of `jar -tvf <yourjarfile>`?

Comment: The `Class-Path` entry should be something like `Class-Path: writeBatchFile/mainFile.class`. But better try to change it to `Class-Path: .`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I can tell you to create the jar using command prompt.

First as your class contains a package `writeBatchFile`, create a folder my the name of `writeBatchFile` and keep the java file in that folder.

Now suppose your folder `writeBatchFile` exists in `G:/`, then open the command prompt in `G:/` and type the following command to compile the class

```
javac writeBatchFile/mainFile.java
```

Remember you must not navigate inside the package folder. Once compiled type the following command to generate the jar

```
jar cfve myJar.jar writeBatchFile/mainFile writeBatchFile/*.class
```

once the jar is generated run the jar by the following command

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

cheers, you are done :)

Comment: except if the goal is to run the jar by clicking it, and not all the properties are set correctly.

Comment: thats completely a different scenario

Comment: but possibly the problem

Comment: yep possibly the case here

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I was able to fix the error by uninstalling JRE and JDK respectively. and re-installing them.

Comment: @skibbi_bizzle If you've solved your problem, please share it with us by using `Add an Answer` button if it's not already there. __[Accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)__ to indicate the best answer or a working solution that helped you the most (and close the question), and [upvote answers which were helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Sorry I am still new to Stack Overflow. I will use the information given to me in the future. My apologies and thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help, I was able to fix the error by uninstalling JRE and JDK respectively and then Re-Installing them. The Manifest file was correct